# Finding the maximum value of a function under uncertainty

Tags: perl, artificial-intelligence, max

I have three values X,Y and Z. These values have a range of values between 0 and 1 (0 and 1 included).
When I call a function f(X,Y,Z) it returns a value V (value between 0 and 1). My Goal is to choose X,Y,Z so that the returned value V is as close as possible to 1.

The selection Process should be automated and the right values for X,Y,Z are unknown.

Due to my Use Case it is possible to set Y and Z to 1 (the value 1 hasn't any influence on the output) and search for the best value of X. 
After that I can replace X by that value and do the same for Y. Same procedure for Z.

How can I find the "maximum of the function"? Is there somekind of "gradient descend" or hill climbing algorithm or something like that?
The whole modul is written in perl so maybe there is an package for perl that can solve that problem?

Comment: we can say, that a value for X,Y and Z with four decimal places is enough. In addition, every computation is time consuming, so a soultion with a few steps is preferred.

Comment: This is the same as finding the root of the partial differentials of *f(x,y,z)*, which can be solved using the [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) if the function can be differentiated. Tell us more about the function.

Comment: Where's the uncertainty part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Simulated Annealing**. Its a multi-variable optimization technique. It is also used to get a partial solution for the Travelling Salesperson problem. Its one of the search algorithms mentioned in Peter Norvig's Intro to AI book as well.

Its a hill climbing algorithm which depends on random variables. Also it won't necessarily give you the 'optimal' answer. You can also vary the iterations required by it as per your computational/time needs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing
http://www1bpt.bridgeport.edu/sed/projects/449/Fall_2000/fangmin/chapter2.htm

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [`Math::Amoeba`](https://metacpan.org/module/Math%3a%3aAmoeba) which implements the *Nelder–Mead method* for finding stationary points on functions.